# Left align icon in Picker Xamarin forms macOS from the default right side

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to customize the Picker for Xamarin forms macOS but without success. I've created a renderer that works fine, but the attributes I add does not seem to make any change to the picker.

The goal is to left align the icon so the text is on the right side. Right now the icon is on the right side, and the text to the left.

```
public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var element = e.NewElement as Picker;

        if (Control != null && element != null)
        {
            Control.Bordered = false;
            Control.Font = NSFont.FromFontName("Helvetica Neue", (System.nfloat)element.FontSize);
            Control.Bordered = false;
            Control.Alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right;

            Control.AttributedTitle = new NSAttributedString("", foregroundColor: element.TextColor.ToNSColor(), paragraphStyle: new NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            {
                Alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right,
                LineSpacing = 0f,
                ParagraphSpacing = 0f,
                ParagraphSpacingBefore = 0f
            });

            Control.ImagePosition = NSCellImagePosition.ImageLeft;
            Control.Cell.ImagePosition = NSCellImagePosition.ImageLeft;

        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        var element = (Picker)this.Element;

        if (e.PropertyName == Picker.ItemsSourceProperty.PropertyName ||
            e.PropertyName == Picker.TitleProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            Control.AddItems(element.Items.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, from shared code, it seems not be useful to modiy the position between text and image.

Comment: Ouch ok, not possible to work with the custom cell?

Comment: Hi, I also want to make sure that whether you want to modify the arrow icon position of the Entry Cell in MacOS?

Comment: no it would be for the Picker

Comment: Okey,  you could share a screenshot of your wanted effect, then I will check that.

Comment: https://ibb.co/170phkj sure so right now it looks liek this by default. i want the arrow on the left side, and text next to it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the image. I have got it, and will check the way to achieve that.

Comment: Hi, I have checked that `Control.Cell.Image` always be null, therefore `ImagePosition` will not work. If it's an issue, you could submit it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) in Github, then we could follow it up there.

Comment: Got it. Do you know if there is a way to hide the pickerbar liek this example? https://www.hiimray.co.uk/2019/10/14/xamarin-forms-quick-and-easy-custom-picker-with-a-more-traditional-look/297 if so, i can make the static design in xamarin forms, then when clicked, show the regular picker window

Comment: Okey, there is a way to hide the arrow icon. You could refer to [NSPopUpButton.ArrowPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopupbutton/arrowposition), and code in Xamarin will be:  `Control.Cell.ArrowPosition = NSPopUpArrowPosition.None;`